# Modal +have+past participal can work as present perfect?

Tags: modal-verbs

Can we use modal+have+past participal for a current events like we use present perfect for present moment. Which one is correct?

1. Just see that car, his father must have bought it for him.
2. Just see that car, his father must buy it for him.

Also,

3. Look your son has made a scratch on my car today he could have broken the glass also.
4. Look your son has made a scratch on my car today he could break the glass also.

Comment: 1 is saying it has already been bought. 2 says that he must buy it in the future (maybe the kid is standing next to it in the car showroom). 3 is saying the son either nearly broke the glass, or the glass it broken and it might have been the son. 4 is suggesting that the son could also break the glass (in the present/near future) - maybe so the person could claim insurance? I think 1&2 need a semi-colon though, possibly 3&4 too.

Comment: So can we use modal+have+past participal like present perfect (action already has happened some time ago but it is relevant at this moment).